# Storing an encrypted password into a database

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, encryption, passwords

I thought this would've been a lot simpler but at this point I'm confused and haven't progressed at all.

Basically, I need to be able to accept  a password from a user in a WPF app, encrypt it then store this in a database and be able to decrypt later on. However I'm not sure how to implement this.

This is completely trivial so whether it's safe or not doesn't matter. All I need is for it to get working only I'm unsure exactly how to do it. I've tried playing around with the DESCryptoServiceProvider() but haven't gotten anywhere.

To be clear, how exactly do I go about converting a simple password into something that's been encrypted and storing it in the database (and what fields would I store it in). At this point, I'm happy if there's only one key and that key is being defined in the source code.

Any suggestions?

Edit: To clarify further, I can't 'encode'. It has to be encrypted for the purposes of this exercise (i.e. it needs to have a key generated). I believe SHA is an encoding algorithm, not encryption.

Comment: Do you really mean that you need to decrypt the password afterwards ? Or do you mean you need to store the encrypted password and then later compare it against another encrypted password ? Do you need to be able to read the original password back out of the database or not ?

Comment: Yeah, my mistake. I just need to compare the two.

Comment: then, it is not called encryption, it is hashing

Comment: You seem to be confused. You say you just need to compare, but you also say you need to encrypt not encode. SHA and other hashing algorithm are exactly what you need to compare two passwords (without needing to store the password). You simply encode the password with the hashing function and compare it to the hash of the password you hashed and store earlier. There it no need to encrypt/decrypt the password, you don't need the password itself to compare against.

Comment: I understand that much. I've used SHA before however in this case (for a school assignment) we're being forced to encode the data. For something to classify as encoding, it needs a key to encode against which is rather different to hashing algorithm.

Comment: If you really, truly, do want to encrypt/decrypt the password, take a look at this http://www.dijksterhuis.org/encrypting-decrypting-string/ That will show you how to encrypt/decrypt a bit of text (i.e. the password you want to encrypt/decrypt) using a passphrase (the passphrase is your "key").

Answer (score 4):

Don't try and code your own scheme for this, you'll likely get something wrong and leave it insecure.

Better use something like [BCrypt](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/10/bcrypt-dotnet-strong-password-hashing-for-dotnet-and-mono.ashx) to do it for you.

And as for how to store it, BCrypt will return a string encoding of the hashed password that is very easy to store in the database.

To be clear, it works like this. When you first store the users password you:

- get the password from the user
- pass the password to the BCrypt HashPassword method
- it returns a string that is the hash of the password
- you store the hash in the database against the user's record

When the user comes to login later you:

- get the password from the user
- get the hash for the user from the database
- pass the hash and the password the user provided to the BCrypt CheckPassword method
- BCrypt returns true or false depending on whether the password matches

Comment: Where would the key be stored?

Comment: What key ? It is very hard from the mixture of terms you are using exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: Apologies. I guess I had gotten myself confused. I took a second look at what my teacher actually stated and took sometime to absorb it. I had confused the distinction between encryption and encoding which, I suppose, is what lead to this mess of a posting.

Answer (score 3):

Is there anything against using one way encryption? SHA would do this - you don't need to decrypt it you only need to check the user is entering the correct password again, which you can do by encrypting their entered password and comparing the resulting hash to the hash stored in your database.

Remember to salt it too!

Answer (score 2):

You need to store an irreversible salted hashcode of the password.

Use `SHA512Managed`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2005 or later, there is [built-in encryption in the database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278098%28SQL.100%29.aspx) that you can use to protect the data without writing your own decrypt/encrypt code.

That article covers SQL 2005 - for SQL 2008 start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510663.aspx).

> Encryption algorithms define data
>   transformations that cannot be easily
>   reversed by unauthorized users. SQL
>   Server allows administrators and
>   developers to choose from among
>   several algorithms, including DES,
>   Triple DES, TRIPLE_DES_3KEY, RC2, RC4,
>   128-bit RC4, DESX, 128-bit AES,
>   192-bit AES, and 256-bit AES.